# Is the @ symbol always necessary in the SharePoint ItemStyle XSLT?

Tags: content-query-web-part, xslt

I'm working on a project in which I've made a new webpart which inherits the CQWP.  In the codebehind I send some additional values, which isn't present in the lists (meaning there are no columns containing these values) I'm displaying using this webpart.

Is it then necessary to use the @ symbol in order to fetch these values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CQWP renders the datatable columns as attributes of the row element so you would use the @ symbol to reference them in your XSLT as opposed to parameters or variables referenced using the $ symbol and elements referenced without any symbol

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing additional parameters using the ModifyXsltArgumentList (or similar)? If so, just add the `<xsl:param name="YourParamName"/>` near the top of the xslt file and you can just get to the parameter names with `$YourParamName`.

Comment: I add an additional column to the datatable.

Comment: Ah, understood. I've worked with code that does this only once before, but I can't quite remember if I needed to use @ or not. I know someone who might know better though...

Comment: Is it possible of you to ask this someone? I'd really appreciate it

Comment: Have done. He might have already blogged about this, so have a rake through his blog - http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/